# Open a new tab when user clicks on the icon

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am new to google extension..

What I want to do in my extension is to display an icon at somewhere in page (Not in the address part nor toolbar but in the left center of the page).

When user clicks on the icon, the new window should open with specific url.

I have already created to do the same by placing icon in toolbar and it works fine.. But I want to display the icon to left-center of the page..

then I tried to display an icon to left center of page by adding element to document.body.. That help me to display the icon but not able to call the browser action or to create new tab on it..

Any suggestion??

Thanks,
Mahesh

Comment: You added the icon and handled onclick event in a *content script*, which has no access to most chrome.* APIs. Use techniques like message passing (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html), you can solve it. But you just want to open a new tab on clicking the icon. Then why not make it a hyperlink with target="_blank"?

Comment: Yes!! You are right...I have solved it by hyperlink..later on i realized it that I can do it  by this simpler way.. You can post this in answer..

Answer (score 0):

I'm just making the comment an answer...

Using `target="_blank"` on the anchor tag worked for me

`<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"><img src="icon.png" /></a>`